# Xarray: Plot all variable data across coordinates in a single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray

Trying to plot one variable, for all existing coordinates into a single line plot. Let's assume a simple example set of data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

temperature = 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(2, 2, 20)

precipitation = 10 * np.random.rand(2, 2, 20)

coord1 = [0, 1]

coord2 = [2, 3]

time = pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=20)

reference_time = pd.Timestamp("2014-09-05")


ds0 = xr.Dataset(

    data_vars=dict(temperature=(["c1", "c2", "time"], temperature),
            
                    precipitation=(["c1", "c2", "time"], precipitation)),

    coords=dict(c1=("c1", coord1),

                c2=("c2", coord2),
        
                time=time,
        
                reference_time=reference_time),

    attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."))
```

**Target plot (sans the title)**:

[image]

I can do this with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ds0.temperature.sel(c1=0,c2=2).plot(ax=ax)
ds0.temperature.sel(c1=0,c2=3).plot(ax=ax)
ds0.temperature.sel(c1=1,c2=2).plot(ax=ax)
ds0.temperature.sel(c1=1,c2=3).plot(ax=ax)
```

I would expect to be able to do this with a syntax of

```
ds0.temperature.plot()
```

But this gives me a histogram plot.

I can assign hue or call subplots in columns

```
ds0.temperature.plot(hue='c1',col='c2')
```

[image]

But I would like to simply have all data in a single plot. Random colors or color coded according to a coordinate would be a welcome addition.

How can I get the target plot without calling all coordinates explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ds0.temperature.stack(stacked=("c1", "c2")).plot.line(x='time')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this works exactly as desired

Answer (score 1):

see the API docs for [`xr.plot.line`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.line.html). you can pass hue and x args to `da.plot.line()`, but you can't provide a list of hues, for example, to determine line color based on iterating through multiple dimensions.

One workaround is to stack the dimension you'd like to plot all lines along:

```py
In [2]: da = xr.DataArray(
   ...:     np.random.random(size=(2, 3, 5)) * np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3, 1),
   ...:     dims=["x", "y", "z"],
   ...:     coords=[range(2), range(3), range(5)],
   ...: )

In [3]: da.stack(stacked=("x", "y")).plot.line(x="z")
```

[image: plot with lines for dimensions x and y]

This isn't awesome, but it does create lines along multiple dimensions in one command. Or you can loop through the dimensions and style it yourself.

Comment: your example uses a DataArray. I tried this with my provided Dataset and it does not seem to work

Comment: but `ds0.temperature` *is* a DataArray

Comment: yeah - just access the temperature attribute and use the same code :)